# Mapping DateDifference with specific first argument across list

Tags: string-manipulation, date-and-time, map

I have a nested list that contains date strings that I've split on the forward slash in the form of year/month/day/hour/minute, like so:

```
list = {{2016, 3, 3, 4, 25}, {2016, 3, 5, 3, 32}, {2016, 3, 8, 11, 54} .....}
```

I want to find the `DateDifference` between every one of these dates and `{2016, 1, 1, 0, 0}` (aka Jan 1st, 2016). I've tried using `Map` as well as attempted to pass the entire list as the second argument of `DateDifference`, but neither has worked; using `Map` only works if I don't provide any arguments to `DateDifference`,

```
DateDifference/@list
```

which will try to take the `DateDifference` between elements (not what I want), and I guess `DateDifference` is not listable. Is there a simple way to do this? I would prefer not to use `DateObjects` as they are very slow.

Comment: `Table[QuantityMagnitude[DateDifference[{2016, 1, 1, 0, 0}, d]], {d, {{2016, 3, 3, 4, 25}, {2016, 3, 5, 3, 32}, {2016, 3, 8, 11, 54}}}]`? (Remove `QuantityMagnitude[]` if you want to keep the units.)

Comment: @J.M.  It is not practical for me to explicitly write every sublist that I want the difference taken from, as my list is quite large. If `Table` is listable though, it might work

Comment: What am I missing here?  `DateDifference[{2016, 1, 1, 0, 0}, #] & /@ {{2016, 3, 3, 4, 
   25}, {2016, 3, 5, 3, 32}, {2016, 3, 8, 11, 54}}` works as expected

Comment: You're supposed to replace the list of dates; e.g. `Table[QuantityMagnitude[DateDifference[{2016, 1, 1, 0, 0}, d]], {d, myLongListOfDates}]` (and of course Jason's proposal is the alternative way to proceed).

Comment: @J.M. This is confusing for me: this piece of code is part of a larger set of pure function + postfix chaining I am doing on a set of imported data; what is `d` supposed to refer to, and how is `d` different from what I would input as `myLongListOfDates`? This list will be fed into the next input as a pure function slot. I'll edit my OP to try and be a bit more clear

Comment: `d` in the `Table[]` code is an index, in much the same way `Table[d!, {d, 1, 5}]` has `d` as an index. Are you familiar with the `foreach` construction in other languages? The equivalent in Jason's proposal is `QuantityMagnitude[DateDifference[{2016, 1, 1, 0, 0}, #]] & /@ myLongListOfDates`.

Comment: @J.M. That makes sense, I am familiar with Python's `for`. Thank you for clarifying.